# Service Fabric FabricRuntime.dll not found

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have tried to upgrade to the ne version of the Service Fabric preview code - 1.4.87-preview - and everything seems to have gone ok, but when I try to deploy a service I get an exception on run telling me that it cannot find FabricRuntime.dll. This goes both for my upgraded project, for newly created test projects and for all samples.

I can see that the DLL is present on the machine and that a system PATH has been set to the directory containing it.

There seems to be nothing wrong with my applications per se, as they deploy fine to a Party Cluster.

Anybody have any idea what is going on. Everything worked fine when I ran the old Service Fabric install. I have tried uninstalling service fabric and installing again, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is now posted on MSDN forums at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6c8cc261-6c84-4097-be03-e8073cbc9397/unable-to-load-dll-fabricruntimedll?forum=AzureServiceFabric&prof=required

Copy of answer from MSDN Forum:

> This is happening because FabricRuntime.dll is looking for zip.dll that ships with Service Fabric runtime. However since JRE is ahead in the PATH list and it also ships with a zip.dll, FabricRuntime tries to load zip.dll from the JRE folder and fails. We have fixed this issue by renaming our DLLs. The fix will be available in the next update of the SDK. In the meanwhile, you can fix this by adding "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code" as the first entry in the system path and then restarting the machine.

Comment: the reboot is not necessary, killing all existing PS sessions should do it

Answer (score 0):

This is the SDK issue, I've opened a GitHub issue at [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/133)